# Why can't I display Unicode math symbols (U+2200..U+22FF)?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I have windows XP and in any application on my computer i don't see this range, nether in IE nor in Notepad++...
I become crazy...

Thank you very much for ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a good Unicode font. For Windows, the typical examples are Arial Unicode MS and Lucida Sans Unicode. At least the first one is included in recent versions (2003+) of Microsoft Word, for instance. Free Unicode fonts include the DejaVu font family. To examine a font, use the charmap.exe utility (Win+R, write charmap, Return; or, if you use Windows Vista/7: Win, write charmap, Return). You have to select "Advanced view" and Group By "Unicode interval". Then you can select "Mathematical Operators".

[image]

Comment: Thenk you for answer. I posted my comment like separate "answer"

Answer (score 0):

Not all fonts support all characters. You probably need to find a font that has glyphs for these characters and select it manually.

Comment: I succeed to select it in notepad but failed in IE